# Apple Push Certificate doesn't work on specific server

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS app that's beta released since yesterday, but since today the push messages that were send via the Apple production server didn't seem to arrive to the users' phones. I recreated the certificate in the Apple Developer Center, tested it on my local server and verified that the new certificate was working.

Then I deployed the new certificate to my live server, but I keep getting this error message:

```
stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused)
```

I've made sure that I really uploaded the new certificate, but even resetting my live server wasn't helping.

I uploaded my project to another live server (a Google Cloud Instance) to verify if the certificate was only working on my local server or if it was just my live server that isn't working properly and the Google live server did deliver the push messages to the devices without an error message.

So it seems my default live server is the only server from where production push messages are not working. The pushes that are sent with the development certificate are delivered from every server successfully by the way.

Why could it be that I can't send push messages from that one specific server? Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if Push Notification can be send from your server or not. That means the port 2195 should be opened in your server to do the same. Due to technical/ security reasons most of the hosting company blocking the port, you can ask them to open it if they can.

You can confirm whether this is opened or not in your server definitively by using telnet and specifying which port to connect to.  From the command line run:

```
MyServer:~ Home$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.34.143...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If there is an error connecting then it will just hang and not return - the above shows a working example where I can connect.

You'll need an SSH login to your hosting service to test it this way, and unfortunately you are unlikely to be able to test it on shared hosting without buying an account for VPS hosting- so you probably have to rely on asking their customer services.

**Note**: However shared hosting from  **Hostgator**, **dreamhost** is working, you can chat with their support team before purchasing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Luckily I already have ssh access to my server. I tried to connect to the sandbox push server as you suggested and the connection was successful. When I tried to connect to the 'production' push server (telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195) however, I got the message 'telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused' (after about 10 seconds). Why can't I connect to the push production server?

Comment: You have to use production certificate to connect to production push. So try with production certificate it will surely work.

Comment: I am using the production certificate, I'm sure of that. For some weird reason I can't connect to Apple's production push server from my default hosting (where I could connect to it before, the push messages have worked earlier). It almost seems like Apple has blocked my specific server from connecting to their production push server, but that is not possible, is it?

Comment: I dont think this can be a issue... ( Apple has blocked my specific server from connecting to their production push server, )

I have an Idea:

Book any VPS hosting for only 1 month for  free or 1 cent & test the pushnotification by putting the same certificates you are using. If that works , you can contact to your hosting provider.

Comment: I actually already did that. I put my code and certificate on a Google cloud instance and the push messages worked. So from your comment it is most likely then that the problem lies with my hosting provider and not with Apple? I will contact them then. Thank you.